# Small problem with increment

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

just having small problem with increment coding.

I have this button and others for adding to a total score:

```
- (IBAction) increaseScore
{
   self.currentScore = self.currentScore + 1;
   currentScoreLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%ld", self.currentScore];
}
```

Every time you press the button you can add 1 and then I have a button that saves the total score.

When leaving the app and returning I can load the total score again but as soon as I press the button it starts back over at 1 anyone know how I can change this? T

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

If you close the application you need to save your data. You can use this code:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:self.currentScore forKey:@"score"];
NSInteger score = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"score"];
```

Ideally you should only use it once when your application starts, but using it every time also works if performance is not a concern.

**update**
Save the data somewhere so it doesn't get reloaded. For example, in your application delegate, which you can access from anywhere with `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]` or keeping a class alive as a singleton with a code like:

```
+(MySharedDataClass *)singleton {
    static dispatch_once_t pred;
    static MySharedDataClass *shared = nil;
    dispatch_once(&pred, ^{
        shared = [[MySharedDataClass alloc] init];
    });
    return shared;
}
```

Otherwise the class containing your values may be unloaded.

Comment: Its not when I close the application, its just when I go to another view. Ill go back to the view and press load and the number appears. But as soon as I start trying to add more to the score it resets to 0 again.

Comment: I agree with Jano. And initially when your application just finished loading, you should check if NSUserDefault is "nil", set its value as default eg say 0. Because for the first time when your application runs NSUserDefault will be zero. You should do this in applicationDidFinishLaunching.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the score to be persistent, there are a couple ways to do that, such as using a plist. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/896644/advice-on-high-score-persistence-iphone-cocoa-touch).

Comment: also, you're probably aware, but just for style you can just use self.currentScore++ instead of self.currentScore = self.currentScore + 1;

Answer (score 0):

When you "...load the total score again..." are you sure that you are setting `self.currentScore = self.totalScore;` in `viewDidLoad:`?

Have you proven you loaded the total score again using break point or through logging?

Comment: Yes it is in the viewDidLoad, the score loads again, its just when I try to add more points after coming back to the view it resets the score to 0.

Comment: Perhaps do a project find on `currentScore` and see if there is any possible code that could be resetting its value.